# EF-Code First Objects don't reflect background DB changes

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, serialization, ef-code-first

I have 3 classes which are mapped to DB tables via entity framework code first.

```
class Device {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual List<Point> Points {get;set;}
}

class Point {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual List<Record> Records {get;set;}
    public virtual Device Device {get;set;}
}

class Record {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public double Value {get;set;}
    public virtual Point Point {get;set;}
}
```

Each `Device` has a list of `Points`, and each `Point` has a list of `Records`, with corresponding navigation properties back to the parents. This all works great except that the connection to the database is lost upon serialization.

The problem: I have a `Device` full of `Points`, each containing 10 `Records`. I serialize the `Device` and close my application. Meanwhile, a collection service application adds 50 more `Records` to each `Point` in the database. When I start my original app and deserialize the `Device`, those points only contain the 10 `Records` from my first run and not the 60 `Records` that actually exist on that `Point` in the database.

Am I thinking about this all wrong? Is there some way for me to force `point.Records` to always get the `Records` from the database?

Comment: You've checked the database and all the data 60 records exist with references to the same point?

Comment: @AlexKrups Yes. If I directly query the db with `dbContext.Points.First().Records.Count` I get the expected 60 records.

Comment: Can you show the code that calls to the DB

Comment: Has your collection Service Commited and saved the changes back to the database when you open your context to retrieve data, or at least when the context issues the DB call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Yes, you're thinking about it wrong.

Entity Framework is an ORM (Object Relational Mapping): in other words, it's one way to link objects to a relational database and have those relationships persist to the object models.

What it is not, however, is two-way binding. You said you've pulled objects from the database, and then serialized them, and then when deserializing them, you're surprised to see that they are the same as when you serialized them.

> The problem: I have a Device full of Points, each containing 10
>   Records. I serialize the Device and close my application. Meanwhile, a
>   collection service application adds 50 more Records to each Point in
>   the database. When I start my original app and deserialize the Device,
>   those points only contain the 10 Records from my first run and not the
>   60 Records that actually exist on that Point in the database.

Think about that for a second: you saved a collection of objects somewhere, and are surprised that they are the same when you retrieved them. I would be alarmed if it worked any other way!

The only way to get them to update and show changes that were made in the database is to actually **go to the database** and retrieve the changes.